# html form posting data

Tags: java, html, post, get

I designed a form in HTML and want to submit the data to a very simple java web server that I made. In the form, I specify the action as "post" so I'd assume that's how it should come into the java web server but "GET" is stuck in front of the URI when I look at it in the debugger. If I were to try and submit the data with the web server turned off, I'd get the "Can't find the page you're looking for message" but I'd see all the data stuck up in the URL. I'm not sure if that's normal.

Can someone just have a look at my HTML page and let me know if I might be doing anything wrong?

```
<head>
    <title>FormTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:1088/mailer.html method="post">
        <div>
            <label>
                First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Last Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" />
            </label>

            </br>

            There's a bunch more text boxes and such here, but you get the idea. 

            <input type="submit" text="Submit!" name="submitBtn" />

        </div>

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Your form action points to an .html page, which most web servers will interpret as a reference to a static page and not to a CGI script, so it will be treated as a GET.  You should change your action to something that is executable on the web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close off the form tag attributes with a quotation mark:

You have -

> ```
>     <form action="http://localhost:1088/mailer.html method="post">
> ```

You need -

> ```
>     <form action="http://localhost:1088/mailer.html" method="post">
> ```

Comment: Jeez.. I can't believe I didn't see that. I'm not that great with HTML yet.. Thank you!

Comment: The worst is when you spend over an hour trying to correct the missing quotation/comma/parenthesis/period mistake...